# When using Pinvoke to pass an LPBYTE

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, pinvoke

I have the delightful (and by delightful I mean painstakingly tedious) job of converted a VB6 application to VB.net. One of the things this application does is communicate with c dll’s (30 of them). After writing a number of the structures and declarations by hand, I decided an automated tool would help save time so I purchased the pinvoke wizard tool.

I ran it threw on of the header files and it successfully generated VB code but I do not understand how to use it, let me give you an example. One of the methods I call is StartSession.
In C the header code is

```
WORD APIENTRY StartSession 
(LPBYTE lpbReturnCode,
LPBYTE lpbErrorMessage,
LPBYTE lpbApplName,
LPBYTE lpbRegionName,
LPBYTE lpbSessionID, 
LPBYTE lpbDataTrunc,
LPBYTE lpbSessionToken,
LPBYTE lpbStandardWait,
LPBYTE lpbVersion,
LPBYTE lpbEnvironment,
LPBYTE lpbESILogonOnly,
LPBYTE lpbMetadataSource,
LPWORD lpbMetadataCacheCount);
```

When I rewrote this function by hand I had written it as

```
Declare Function StartSession Lib "chat2.dll" (ByVal ReturnCode As String _
                                               , ByVal ErrorMsg As String _
                                               , ByVal ApplicationName As String _
                                               , ByVal RegionName As String _
                                               , ByVal EmulatorSessionID As String _
                                               , ByVal DataTruncationFlag As String _
                                               , ByVal SessionToken As String _
                                               , ByVal StandardWait As String _
                                               , ByVal ApplicationVersion As String _
                                               , ByVal Environment As String _
                                               , ByVal ESILogonOnly As String _
                                               , ByVal ScreenDescDataSource As String 
                                               , ByRef ScreenDataCacheCount As Short)
```

When I called this method, I submitted null terminated char arrays 
ex.

```
Dim param1 As Char()
param1(0) = "c"c
param1(1) = "a"c
param1(2) = "t"c
param1(3) = ChrW(0)
StartSession (param1,...)
```

The pinvoke wizard generated the following stub

```
<DllImport("chat2.dll")> _
Public Function StartSession( _
        ByRef lpbReturnCode As Byte _
        , ByRef lpbErrorMessage As Byte _
        , ByRef lpbApplName As Byte _
        , ByRef lpbRegionName As Byte _
        , ByRef lpbSessionID As Byte _
        , ByRef lpbDataTrunc As Byte _
        , ByRef lpbSessionToken As Byte _
        , ByRef lpbStandardWait As Byte _
        , ByRef lpbVersion As Byte _
        , ByRef lpbEnvironment As Byte _
        , ByRef lpbESILogonOnly As Byte _
        , ByRef lpbMetadataSource As Byte _
        , ByRef lpbMetadataCacheCount As Short _
        ) As Short
End Function
```

How can I use a single byte to represent a null terminated string of characters?

Comment: What was the errors, outputs, anything?

Comment: No I just don't know how to turn the char array into a byte?

Comment: This is hopeless, even the *one* argument that seems like it might have the correct type (lpbMetadataCacheCount) has the wrong name.  Run man, run!

Comment: Have you actually **tried** to run this code?

Comment: With the methods that I built by hand, where in my declarations I called the parameters String's. I ran the code and it worked. With the tool i bought, it made the parameters byte's which makes sence because in the original C code the params were LPBYTE. Now that I have changed all my declarations to byte I cannot compile the code, because I don't know how to pass the strings to the methods.

Comment: The reason I don't just keep them as strings is because I have to pass complex objects in other methods and thos complex objects in C code were called LPVOID and I need to find a way to send that data to the method

Comment: You should refer to the docs for P/Invoke Wizard or contact the vendor to see if there's some configuration that can be done to convince the tool that `LPBYTE` means "null terminated string" instead of "pointer to a single byte" or "pointer to an array of bytes". A C declaration of `char*` (I assume that `LPBYTE` is synonym for `char*` or a close relative) doesn't distinguish between any of those - only how the pointer gets used does. To handle the ambiguity, I'd expect that the tool would provide some degree of configurability.

Comment: As for your money back, that tool doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

To the question:

> How can I use a single byte to represent a null terminated string of
>   characters?

The simple answer is "You don't."

That's not really what is going on in the code anyway.  First off, `ByRef someVar As Byte` is not passing a Byte to the API.  It is passing a *pointer* to a byte.  So on the native side, the code is getting an address of that byte.  Now if that address points the the *first* byte in a buffer of bytes containing your string's characters and is (likely) null-terminated, it is easy for that API to read that content upto that null and act upon it.

And you could actually use unsafe code blocks in C# or maybe GCHandle pinng or something in the Marshal class or MarshalAs attributes to mimic this by doing something like `StartSession(myParam1Buff[0], etc, etc);`.

But don't.  You need to read the docos (not just the header files) and determine what the API is expecting and the use `StringBuilder` or '`String` instances decorated with the correct MarshalAs attribute with the [UnmanagedType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx) flag set based on the doco.  Most likely, it will be `LPStr`.